# JS, как сделать, чтобы рандом не повторялся?

Tags: javascript, случайные-числа

Пытаюсь реализовать игру, где выдается картинка и четыре варианта ответов, один из которых верный. Как написать или переписать функцию, чтобы рандомно выпадающая в поле field картинка не повторялась, пока не закончится основной массив с объектами actress? Я только обучаюсь, поэтому буду признательна, если опишете логику и пример решения как можно более простым языком.

```
function getStarted() {
    let arr = [];

    function random(max, count) {

        while (arr.length < count) {
            let j = (Math.floor(Math.random() * max));
            if (!arr.includes(j)) {
            arr.push(j); 
            }
        } 
        
    }
    random(actress.length, 4);

    function getRandom () {
    
        let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
        a = actress[arr[0]].name;
        b = actress[arr[1]].name;
        c = actress[arr[2]].name;
        d = actress[arr[3]].name;
        image = actress[arr[rand]].photo;
        descr = actress[arr[rand]].name;
    }
    getRandom();

    function beginning () {
        firstBtn.innerHTML = a;
        secondBtn.innerHTML = b;
        thirdBtn.innerHTML = c;
        fourthBtn.innerHTML = d;
        field.innerHTML = `<img src=${image} alt=${descr}>`;
    }    
    beginning();
}

start.addEventListener('click', () => {
    
    getStarted(); 
    
});
```

Comment: [Фишер-Йейтс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80).

Answer (score 3):

1. Берём массив
2. Перемешиваем его каим-либо образом с самого начала
3. Далее просто берём элементы по порядку из перетасованного массива.

Comment: То есть, я пропускаю шаг с созданием массива arr из 4х значений, и беру через innerHTML в кнопки просто первые 4 номера из перетасованного изначального массива? Но тогда возникает проблема, что картинка всегда будет равняться одной и той же кнопке. А если картинку брать через rand из перетасованного массива, то ее может вообще не быть на кнопке. Кажется, я не совсем понимаю, как использовать этот алгоритм.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант Алексея самый оптимальный. Но приведу так же свой алгоритм.

1. Создаем массив в котором будут хранится уже "использованные" элементы вашего массива с вариантами ответа
2. Берем рандомный вариант ответа
3. Проверяем, что его еще нет в массиве с "использованными" вариантами
4. Сохраняем его в наш массив для "использованных" элементов

у вас в принципе такая схема в методе random реализована

> if (!arr.includes(j))

Comment: А вы не могли бы подсказать, на каком этапе этот новый массив создавать и как потом использовать? Потому что я пробую создать его тут:
```
 let newArr = [];

  let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
   if (!newArr.includes(rand)) {
        newArr.push(rand);
     }
   a = actress[arr[0]].name;
   b = actress[arr[1]].name;
   c = actress[arr[2]].name;
   d = actress[arr[3]].name;
   image = actress[arr[rand]].photo;
   descr = actress[arr[rand]].name;
```
и он добавляет по одному элементу от 0 до 3, а нужно добавлять именно элемент исходного массива, а не массива arr.